# SugarRecord how to change some property and save it

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sugarrecord

I have an method that helps me to save a new object to storage:

```
 try! db.operation { (context, save) -> Void in
      let object: Device = try! context.new()

      object.address = self.tempDevice.address

      try! context.insert(object)
      save()
    }
```

But how can I modify `Device` that I already created using `SugarRecord`

Comment: Hey Alexander, can you check out this issue?
https://github.com/carambalabs/SugarRecord/issues/279

Comment: @PedroPiñeraBuendia, yea looks like a solution, will try it. thank you!